# How to I create a button in shiny to launch an R script?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like my HTML page to have a text field where the user can enter the path to his R script and next to it I would like to have a button that actually executes the script. I have not seen any similar examples. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This would be a bad idea from a security point of view

Comment: I have that in mind when designing the script/interface.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce